# How to make Entity Framework auto-increment IDs when using code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm using the code-first approach and because of that I do not have the `.edmx` file so I cannot change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` attribute. How do I then make EF auto-increment the IDs? (right now all IDs are zeros by default)

Comment: what you are looking for is `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` with `DatabaseGeneratedOption` as `Identity`.

Comment: When I use DatabaseGeneratedOption.None it doesn't auto-increment, but when I use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity it doesn't even generate the Id (leaves it null)

Answer (score 1):

A primary key *with auto-increment* (default behavior) is generated if any of the following holds true:

- The class contains a property named *"Id"*
- The class contains a property named *$className + "Id"*
- The property of interest is annotated with [KeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Might it be that your property is named "ID" instead of "Id" without the Key attribute?

Comment: I use the Key attribute and the property is named Id

Comment: What is the type of the property? `int` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to specify keys using EF code first:

- Use built-in code conventions (his first two bullets)
- Use the KeyAttribute data annotation directly on the property/field
- Use the Fluent API to specify the key field